# Scroll down doesn't repeat after achieving the end of the body

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to repeat scrolling again from the fist of div, but it works only one time when page is loaded.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="next-section blue">First Section</div>
  <div class="next-section red">Second Section</div>
  <div class="next-section green">Second Section</div>
  <div class="next-section yellow">Second Section</div>
</div>
<button class="down-btn">Click to go to the next section</button>
```

```
var i = 0;
$('.down-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  i++;
  var offset = $("div.next-section").eq(i).offset().top;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 400);
});
```

So, when scroll has reached the end, then by clicking this button, this should start again from first section
LINK: https://jsfiddle.net/uj91djeL/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reset the index variable `i` to 0 when it reaches the end, i.e equals the length of all the sections.

```
var i = 0;
$('.down-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  i++;
  var nextSection$ = $("div.next-section") 
  if(i === nextSection$.length) i=0;
  var offset = nextSection$.eq(i).offset().top;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 400);
});
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gwoeqdk/2/)